# Django filtering with Custom primary key

Tags: django, primary-key, django-filter

I have two tables and I want to get the "description" field.
This is what I have currently.

```
class BuildingNumber(BaseModel): 
   number = models.CharField(_("number"),max_length=200,primary_key=True) 
   description = models.CharField(_("description"), max_length=200)
 
class SchoolNumber(BaseModel):
  school = models.ForeignKey(School,max_length=200,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  school_number = models.ForeignKey(BuildingNumber, max_length=200,on_delete=models.CASCADE) def __str__(self): return str(self.school)



school_number =SchoolNumber.objects.filter(school__in=school_list).values("s_number")

description = BuildingNumber.objects.filter(number__in=school_number).values("description")
print("description: ",description)
```

And for the BuildingNumber model I am using my custom primary key, not the django default 'id'.
However this didn't work.

I got the following error:

```
ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 1: ...._number" WHERE "...."."number" IN (SELECT...
```

I read that this happens when you use a custom primary key. But i need to use this and I coudn't find a way to overcome this error

Comment: Can you share both models? SchoolNumber.s_number and BuildingNumber.number appear to be incompatible types

Comment: Please share the given models.

Comment: [code block] (class BuildingNumber(BaseModel):
    number = models.CharField(_("number"), max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(_("description"), max_length=200) 

class SchoolNumber(BaseModel):
   
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, max_length=200,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_number = models.ForeignKey(BuildingNumber, max_length=200,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.school))

@IainShelvington

Comment: sorry dont know how to properly format it.. @IainShelvington

Comment: @DidemDurukan show the School model. As we wrote above: it is quite possible that the list “s_number” contains values of a different type.